# Calculating the Gradient Vector of a function with Mathematica and then fitting it into Latex

Tags: latex, wolfram-mathematica

I calculated the gradient vector of a function in Mathematica and I have to make a .tex document and then compile it into pdf. the code is this:

```
\left\{-\frac{x z u^{(0,0,1)}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}-\frac{x^2}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}\right) u^{(1,0,0)}
\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)-\frac{x y u^{(0,1,0)}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}},-\frac{y z u^{(0,0,1)}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}-\frac{y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}\right) u^{(0,1,0)}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)-\frac{x y u^{(1,0,0)}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}},\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}-\frac{z^2}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}\right) u^{(0,0,1)}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)-\frac{y z u^{(0,1,0)}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{x z u^{(1,0,0)}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}\right\}
```

How do I fit it into the pdf? how do I split this? none of the methods I know for splitting seem to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow, It could give a good idea about how to write a good question in StackOverflow https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Try Tex.staxkexchange.com instead.